# Prove that the following spaces are complete/not

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to show if the following facts are true/false:

- $(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete.
- $ [0,1]$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.

Since usual metric  gives usual topology and  we know  that $(0,1)$ is not complete with usual metric so the first question is false.

Since usual metric  gives usual topology and  we know  that $[0,1]$ is  complete with usual metric so the second  question is also false.

Are the justifications correct?Please help

Comment: We know it's false because it is false? On what planet would those be acceptable justifications? Of course those justifications aren't enough! So why do you know either of those things? You wouldn't have said them if you didn't have reasons. What are the reasons?

Comment: FWIW you do have the correct answers.  Now you just have explain *why* (0,1) is not complete and [0,1] is.

Comment: My answers are not correct;I just found that 1 is true and 2 is false@fleablood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that it is possible that a metrizable topological space $(X,\tau)$ supports two different metrics $d_1,d_2$ that induce the topology $\tau$ for which $(X,d_1)$ is complete but $(X,d_2)$ isn't.

For the first question, note that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Choose some homeomorphism $f \colon (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define a metric $d$ on $(0,1)$ by $d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, $d$ induces the usual topology on $(0,1)$ but $f$ is an isometry and so $d$ is complete.

For the second question, note that $[0,1]$ with the usual topology is compact and any compact metric space is complete.